# ssh: why my disabled forward X11 for specific host don't work?

Tags: ssh, x11, dropbear

I use an alias for ssh

```
alias ssh
alias ssh='ssh -t -K -Y
```

I want to use ssh forwarding X11 except for one host
so i did this:

```
vim .ssh/config

host myhost
   port 22
   ForwardX11 no
   HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
   PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

but..

```
ssh myhost 
sh: xauth: command not found
myuser@myhost$
```

seems my option is ignored..why?

I also tried

```
   ForwardX11 no
   ForwardX11trusted no
```

but no success.

A workaround can be this...

```
\ssh myhost
```

so -t -K -y is ignored, but I prefer a more clean solution

I forgot: the remote server use dropbear

reading [this page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-dropbear/) i see is possible to disable X11 for a specific key on server

vim .ssh/authorized_keys

```
no-X11-forwarding ssh-rsa......
```

but in this case it refuse also \ssh command!

```
ssh myhost
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Connection to myhost closed by remote host.
Connection to myhost closed.

\ssh myhost 
Connection to myhost closed by remote host.
Connection to myhost closed.
```

Using this line on server works..but no for pubkey, it require the password

```
no-agent -forwarding, no-port-forwarding, no-x11-forwarding ssh-rsa....
```

Comment: Side note: `alias ssh='ssh -t -K -Y` is not a complete command. I assume the missing quote is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Preliminary note

You tagged [dropbear](/questions/tagged/dropbear) but I doubt your SSH *client* is from Dropbear (i.e. I doubt your `ssh` is in fact `dbclient`; I guess `dbclient` does not even support all the options you used). Therefore this answer investigates the behavior of SSH client from OpenSSH.

(Personally I expect any client to copy the behavior of OpenSSH in aspects that matter to the question. The point is OpenSSH is the de-facto standard for SSH implementations.)

---

#### Analysis

From [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#DESCRIPTION):

> `ssh(1)` obtains configuration data from the following sources in the following order:
>
> 1. command-line options
> 2. user's configuration file (`~/.ssh/config`)
> 3. system-wide configuration file (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`)
>
> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used. […]

By using the alias, you're using `ssh -Y`. The command-line option makes `ssh` ignore `ForwardX11 no` in your config file. If you want an option from the config file to work, you mustn't use any opposing command-line option. Command-line options matter first and this is it.

---

#### Solution

You wrote:

> I want to use ssh forwarding X11 except for one host

Instead of in the alias, implement this in your config file:

```
host myhost
   ForwardX11 no

host *
   ForwardX11 yes
   ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Note the manual states:

> Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the file, and general defaults at the end.

This means `host myhost` shall be before `host *`, exactly like in the example above, not the other way around.